# MySql Duplicate entries with auto updating context sensitive relations in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

Is there any possibility to duplicate specific entries by auto updating context sensitive relations?

Given a table 'table1' like:

[image]

My goal is to duplicate all entries with categoryId 42 while updating parentId if neccessary:

[image]

id is an auto incremented column and parentId is used to identify relations between the entries.

Currently I'm inserting them one by one, selecting the old data and managing the logic for the parentId in PHP.

```
//Thats simplified what I do ($conn is a Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract)
$rows = $conn->fetchAll("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE categoryId = 42 ORDER BY parentId ASC");
$newIds = [];
foreach($rows as $row){
    if(array_key_exists($row['parentId'],$newIds))
        $row['parentId'] = $newIds[$row['parentId']];
    else
        $row['parentId'] = null;

    $conn->query("INSERT INTO table1 (parentId,info,categoryId) VALUES (?,?,?)",[$row['parentId'],$row['info'],$row['categoryId']]);

    $newId = $conn->lastInsertId('table1');

    $newIds[$row['id']] = $newId;
}
```

I'm stuck with this because I need the lastInsertedId of the new element to set the new parentId for the next one.
But I'm experiencing this to be pretty slow (in relation to one single query which contains the logic).

Is there any possibility to give a query some kind of incremental element sensitive logic? Or have you any suggestions on how to fasten this up?

Any help appreciated! :)

Comment: Create table here, do not use external images.

Comment: Didn't figure out how to use tables. In the advanced help it says:
Tables are only available in Documentation pages.

Answer (score 0):

You are not showing any code. I guess you use mysqli_insert_id() to get the last inserted ID. Maybe you can do something with MAX(ID)+1.

Something like:

```
INSERT INTO table1 
  SELECT MAX(ID)+1, 
  info, 
  categoryId    
FROM 
  table1
WHERE .............. -- the conditions to retreive the parent
```

Comment: Thanks for your help RWC.
I added code. I'm not having problems with the auto increment part because MySql handles this by itself.
Any idea if its possible to only use mysql to do what php does right now?

Comment: I think you misunderstood. Auto increment is handled by MySql. That is not what I suggest. look again.

Comment: Ok I got you now. I could use your attempt if it would be guaranteed that all data is in correct order (parents always before their children). With the example data there would be a problem while copying element with id 4. Because the element with MaxID wouldn't be the parent but an element on the same hierarchal layer as the copy of element with id 4 itself.
After a lot of further research I endet up leaving the logic in php. But made some structure changes to prepare the data in a better way and to decrease the query count.
But thanks for your help anyways! :)